# Why does my table appear onload but not my chart?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have 2 functions, 1 to draw a chart, another to draw a table.
I did a

```
<body onload="getchart();gettable();">
```

but only the table gets drawn out onload! 
So, I did a

```
<body onload="gettable();getchart();">
```

but oppositely, only the chart gets drawn out onload!

May I know how to draw both chart and table onload? Thank you~
My Codes down below (I did not include the server side php to mysql codes here) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function gettable(string,strings)
{
var a=string;
var b=strings;
if(a == null && b == null)
{
a = new Date().getFullYear();
b = "";
}

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("inputtable").innerHTML =     xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","GetTableData.php?q="+a+"&v="+b,true);

    xmlhttp.send();
        }

 function getchart(str)
        {
var b=str;
if(b == "")
{
b = new Date().getFullYear();
}
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("inputchart").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            var a=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);


            ab=a[1];
            cd=a[2];
            ef=a[3];
            gh=a[4];

            //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMouseoverVisualization());
            drawMouseoverVisualization();

        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","getData.php?q="+b,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


    function drawMouseoverVisualization() {
      var barsVisualization;
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

      data.addColumn('number', 'Quarter');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Frequency');
      data.addRows([[1,ab],[2,cd],[3,ef],[4,gh]]);


      var options={
          hAxis: {title: 'Quarter'},
          vAxis: {title: 'Frequency'},
          trendlines: {0: {type: 'exponential', //type: 'polynomial',type: 'linear'
                            degree:3,
                           color: 'red'      
            }}
      };

      barsVisualization = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
      barsVisualization.draw(data, options);

    };
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});


            </script>
</head>

<body onload="getchart();gettable();">

    <div id="inputchart" style="visibility: hidden"></div>

    <form>
        <select name="years" id="years" onchange="getchart(this.value)">
            <?php
            echo "<option>Select year</option>";
            for ($i=2016;$i<date("Y")+10;$i++){
            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </form>
           <div id="chart"></div>


    <form>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" onkeyup="gettable(year.value,this.value)">
        <select name="year" id="year" onchange="gettable(this.value,search.value)">
            <?php
            echo "<option value=2016>Select year</option>";
            for ($i=2016;$i<date("Y")+10;$i++){
            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";}
            ?>
        </select>

</form>
     <div id="inputtable"></div>


</body>
```

Comment: The content of `function gettable()` starting on line 1 should be wrapped in curly brackets.

Comment: Oh im sorry i did add it in but it is still the same. i accidentally deleted the bracket when i pasted my codes here.

Comment: I just ran your entire code, adding the lines `alert ("gettable");` and `alert ("getchart");` at the beginning of each of those functions, and both functions were called. Check the console for error messages, and check the 'network' tab in the Developer Tools to see what response is coming from the xmlhttp request

Comment: There's nothing in the console and when i looked at the network, there's no xmlhttp requests until I select an option in the textbox. But I do not know why the table appears by itself.

Comment: Maybe because the inline style attribute of the `inputchart` div: `<div id="inputchart" style="visibility: hidden">`?

Comment: yes i've tried to remove the visibility as hidden but my chart is held in the <div id="chart"></div> not the <div id="inputchart"></div>

Comment: Thanks a lot grateful! Quentin solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `xmlhttp` as a global variable.

Whichever function you run second overwrites the first value you assigned to it.

Avoid globals. Use local variables. Add `var`.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still a beginner at this. Do I just add var infront of every single xmlhttp?

Comment: WOW great! I just added the var in some xmlhttp and both the chart and the table appeared! Thank a lot Quentin! Appreciate it! :)

Comment: You need to specify `var` when you declare a variable inside a function. It is usually a good idea to run in strict mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode (as that would prevent this error)

Comment: Thanks a lot Quentin! I'll read up o the strict mode and use it in my future projects. Thank you once again! :)

Comment: Hey Quentin, I am stuck once again. As my table is from a php file, I can't use the row onclick function. Do you have any idea on how to do that? I'll post a new thread.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you need a space in between the calling of the two functions.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm

Otherwise you could create a function in your js that reads something like this:

```
function start () {func1(); func2();}
```

And just call start() when body is loaded.

Comment: I've googled it too before posting here and i've tried solutions like that but it isn't working for me. I read that the codes are meant to be read by the order they were placed but shouldn't both my chart and table both be shown since both functions run onload? What has the order got to do with which table or chart gets shown? I'm really confused and I can't find any error in my codes.

Comment: No. Whitespace has absolutely no meaning there.